# Gradle - paths in multi-project builds

Tags: gradle, path, build.gradle

I have a multi-project gradle project with following directory structure:

```
+ project_root
    + module1
        + src
        build.gradle

    + module2
        + src
        build.gradle

    + web
        ..

    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
```

In `module1/build.gradle` among other things I have specified:

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
    outputFile = "web/script.js"
}
```

It is a special Kotlin JS setting that specifies output file path of compiled JS file.

Now my problem is, that when I build the whole project (`project_root/build.gradle`) the file ends up in the right directory (`project_root/web`), but when I accidentally run build on the module alone the file is saved in module directory (`project_root/module1/web`).

How can I fix paths in my build scripts, so file output will be saved in exactly the same directory no matter which build script I run (without specifying full path, I want a relative path)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what Gradle plugin requires the path parameter in your code example, but all regular (non-3rd-party) Gradle plugins evaluate path parameters via [`Project.files(Object...)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#files(java.lang.Object...)) to avoid different locations when calling Gradle from various working directories.

I would suggest to use the above method (or its single file version [`Project.file(Object)`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#file(java.lang.Object))) as well. You can even omit the `project` part, because the `build.gradle` file gets executed in the project scope:

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions {
    outputFile = file('web/script.js')
}
```

This will always evaluate the path relative to the project directory of the project your `build.gradle` belongs to. To evaluate a file relative to the project directory of the root project, use `rootProject.files(Object...)`, for a path relative to the project directory of a subproject or any project in the build, use `project(':path:to:project').files(Object...)`.

Comment: This saved me a couple of hours!Thanks